# Creating different instances in a loop using a dictionary

Tags: python, class, oop, dictionary, instantiation

I would like a user defined a series of strings

```
user_input = ('cat', 'cactus', 'cat')
```

which correspond to a series of objects to be instantiated from a dictionary of possible objects

```
classes = {
    'cat': Cat,
    'cactus': Cactus,
 }
```

Where the `Cat` and `Cactus` correspond to classes which descend from a parent class

```
class Pet():
    ...

class Cat(Pet):
    def __init__(self, name, colour):
        Pet.__init__(self, name, colour)
        ...

class Cactus(Pet):
    def __init__(self, name, colour):
        Pet.__init__(self, name, colour)
        ...
```

I try to add object type to a list

```
pet_types = []
for i in range(0,3):
    try:
        pet_type.append(classes[user_input[i]])
    except:
        raise Exception('type no exist')
```

But when I do this the exception is raised telling me "type no exist" when the string corresponds exactly to the dictionary entry! Why is this happening?

I then want to use `pet_types` like this

```
pet_500 = pet_types[500](name,colour)
```

Comment: Start by not using a blanket `try...except`. What is the *actual exception* being raised?

Comment: Side note: don't loop over `range()` when you could just loop ever `user_input` directly.

Comment: I think you're looking for a factory pattern. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Catching any exception (`except:`) is a dodgy practice, as is hiding the original exception with your own, without even logging it.

The combination of these two dodgy practices in this case hid the fact that you have a typo, and you're trying to access the undefined `pet_type` (singular), instead of the variable you actually have - `pet_types` (plural). Fix it and you should be fine.

Comment: Yes you're correct, that is a bit embarrassing! It works fine and without the exception being thrown. In future I won't add the custom exception!!